# ubuntu 15.04 AMd motherboard

Tags: ati

I have desktop with AMD ATHLON X2 210 Processor and motherboard Gigabyte GA-M68MT-S2 (nF630a)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on this machine and it works fine

I've tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 but failed - i have used different modes on install but without success

So now I wonder - would Ubuntu 15.04 work on this machine? Maybe Ubuntu crew made some fixes in 15.04 to make it work on AMD chipsets?

Also which version of Ubuntu 15.04 to try - 32 bit or 64 bit? maybe here can be problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does it fail to boot from live USB/CD or to load the installer? Any ubuntu version released after 12.04 should work without any issues on your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a problem with the which OS version you have. I myself have an AMD cpu & gpu, with an asus m5a99fx motherboard. How many gigabytes of memory do you have? I'm sure you know this but 32bit is 2GB or under, 64bit is 2GB and above. Again I would just double check the OS version because i've installed my 14.04 disk on 3 different computers. Hope this helps!

Comment: 4 Gb memory on this machine

Comment: I wonder why it would work on one version, but not another.

Comment: Goodmorning Gentlemen,
(It's morning in The Netherlands),

Have you gave it a thought to do an installation over the internet, by using a minimal cd image?

The community has a nice helpfull topic on their [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). Here you can find the image suitable for your computer architecture.

Comment: hello! Maybe you can help

Comment: Gigabyte motherboards can be frustratingly unable to boot the Ubuntu live USB. The Ubuntu minimal CD/USB is text only, so it will boot on almost anything, see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/665020/cant-boot-ubuntu-but-debian-can-help-me-please/671543#671543 You should install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu since your computer has 4GB RAM.

Comment: thank you all for your help - i'll try mininmal installation